# How to delete git repository(laravel project) on visual studio code

Tags: laravel, git

I have small laravel project that committed to git. Then I successfully deleted a remote repository by manually(Setting -> Delete this repository), it work fine. But once I try to make new repository on vs code, then I got

```
$ git init
Reinitialized existing Git repository in C:/xampp/htdocs/uploadcanvas/.git/
```

Actually, this repository already deleted. But I may need to clear some cache/file to create new repository. But I'm do not know how to manage that.

Any advise or guidance would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that you do delete .git folder from uploadcanvas folder?

Comment: Dear  ramin ashrafimanesh, It work since .git deleted.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I think you can delete `.git` folder.

Comment: Additional hint: it is a hidden folder, so you need to show hidden files in order to see the .git folder.

Answer (score 10):

Try with below command

```
sudo rm -rf .git
```

then

```
git init
```

Answer (score 7):

I think you should delete your .git folder. But unfortunately, .git folder is hidden by default. You can remove it in your settings > Files:Exclude. save your work, save your work. You should see the .git folder now so you can delete it

Answer (score 0):

In Git Bash (Windows)

```
rm -rf .git
```

to remove .git folder.